# Rerun function on error and pass result up

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2

I have separated my api call into three layers.  The `component`, the `repository`, and the `apihelper`.  I want the logic for `refresh_tokens` to be in `apihelper.js`.  When I do this it seems like the `apihelper` runs again after getting the `401` response status but it never passes the data back up to the `component`.  I know I could put the logic to rerun it in the component but that seems like it will end up being a lot of duplicate code as I add more calls.  I feel like it's probably caused by my shallow understanding of javascript promises but I'm a javascript beginner.

Component

```
<script>
import breweryrepository from '@/repository/breweryrepository.js'
export default {
    mounted() {
        this._getTotalBreweries();
    },
    methods: {
        _getTotalBreweries() {
            breweryrepository.getTotalBreweries()            
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.data)
                    {
                        this.totalNumberOfBreweries = response.data.totalBreweries;
                    }
                })
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            totalNumberOfBreweries: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Repository

```
import apihelper from '@/helpers/ApiHelper.js';

export default {  

  getTotalBreweries() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(apihelper.apiCall('/brewery/totalnumber'));
    });      
  }
}
```

Apihelper

```
import axios from 'axios';
var querystring = require('querystring');
import { store } from '../store/store.js';
import auth from '@/auth/auth.js'

export default {       
  apiCall(url) {
    return axios.get(store.state.baseUrl + url, { 'headers': auth.getAuthHeader() })
      .catch((error) => {                    
        if(error.response.status == 401)
        {
          console.log("401 error, running refresh and apicall again");
          auth.refreshToken();
          this.apiCall(url);                          
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaand I wasn't returning the call.

```
return this.apiCall(url);
```

Works now